# Can't get buttons to append to textarea

Tags: php, javascript, html

I'm building a restaurant menu application in PHP & JavaScript
And I can't seem to get the buttons to append the text area when the ordering is being placed...(This is just test code at present) Here's my code:

```
$test = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM main_stock");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($test)){
echo "<div id='".$row["RCode"]."'><a href='javascript:addTo(".$row["Name"].",".$row["RCode"].")'>".$row["Name"]."</a></div>";}
```

And my javascript function is as follows:

```
function addTo(name, Rcode) {
document.getElementById('order').value += name;
}
```

And HTML Form is as follows:

```
    <form id="OrderForm" name="OrderForm" method="post" action="">
  <p>
    <label>
      <textarea name="order" id="order" cols="35" rows="20" readonly="readonly">test</textarea>
    </label>
  </p><table>
  <tr><td>Subtotal:</td><td><input type="text" id="subtotal" readonly="readonly" value="2.00" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Tax:</td><td><input type="text" id="tax" readonly="readonly" value="2.00"/></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Total:</td><td><input type="text" id="total" readonly="readonly" value="4.00"/></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" id="submit" value="Send Order To Kitchen"/></td></tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: What is the resulting markup that the browser receives? And are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: Have you ever used jfiddle? If not, it might help you test out your code, for example: http://jsfiddle.net/XtZMT/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the `echo` may be resulting in invalid JavaScript syntax. E.g.:

```
addTo(Something, Inc.,STI)
```

Rather than:

```
addTo("Something, Inc.","STI")
```

You'll need to output additional quotes for JavaScript to use. And, since you're already using `"` for the PHP string and `'` for HTML attributes, this will require escaping -- or encoding:

```
echo "... href='javascript:addTo(&quot;".$row["Name"]."&quot;,&quot;".$row["RCode"]."&quot;)'>...";
```

Another option may be to use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode) since JSON is based from JavaScript syntax:

```
echo "... href='javascript:addTo(".json_encode($row["Name"]).",".json_encode($row["RCode"]).")'>...";
```

Answer (score 0):

`TEXTAREAs` don't have a `.value`, they have `.innerHTML`

Comment: "[*don't have a `.value`*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLTextAreaElement#Properties)?"

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
document.getElementById('order').innerText += name;
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing with ID `'order'` in your example.

Instead of `document.getElementById('order')`, try `document.getElementById(Rcode)`.

Comment: See Updated with added HTML